# How does limit_conn_log_level works?

Tags: nginx

Syntax: limit_conn_log_level info | notice | warn | error;

Default: limit_conn_log_level error;

"*Sets the desired logging level for cases when the server limits the number of connections.*"

What does this mean exactly? Can i see an example of the output of the different options?

So if i set it to error, and rate limit kicks it will be logged as an error? Meaning it will show up in the error log instead of the access log?

What changes if i set it to info vs  notice, or warn?

Comment: as it twlls, when max numbers of connections reached it should get that debug level as i understood in the past this variable